# Are there any good tutorials for Solr for a noob?

Tags: php, solr

I dont understand Solr are there any good tutorials except the one provided intheir official page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also dont have much concept about `Solr`, but a [simple google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=solr) brought up a great list of some thing that might help you:

1. [Official tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html)
2. [Official JavaDocs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/index.html)
3. [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr)
4. [Another Tutorial PDF](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/solr/tags/release-1.1.0/site/tutorial.pdf&ei=APH5TaXdJ4aurAeMvcXJDw&usg=AFQjCNGIeXBvG2XiEwvu1531TPYlv3Sf7g)
5. [FAQs about SOLR](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ)
6. [Tutorial 1](http://synapticloop.com/blog/solr-tutorial/)
7. [Tutorial 2](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1668)
8. [Tutorial 3](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html)

Answer (score 9):

I had to learn Solr, and I documented most of what I learned along the way. It might be useful: 
http://blog.kevindoran.co/solr-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The official tutorial is useful, but very short. I found this tutorial to be extremely helpful:

http://www.solrtutorial.com/index.html

(This is from the same person who produced Tutorial 4 in the first answer, but that link actually points to a Lucene tutorial, not a Solr tutorial.)

Answer (score 0):

A good book which teached me a lot of stuff in solr is 'Solr Enterprise Search Server' from PACKT. ISBN: 978-1-847195-88-3 although there is a new version of this book.

It will learn you what the capabillities are with solr and how you can use/install/configure it from step by step.