# Index data from multiple tables into solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to index two tables from mySQL database into solr. Here are the steps:

Step: 1 Change the data-config

Step 2: The schema.xml should have the solr_details field

Step 3: Run the full-import command
please see the website: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart

Can someone explain step 2 to me. What does he mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

`solr_details` is a field defined in the `schema.xml`, like any other field `'solr_id'`, `'solr_name'` etc..  mentioned in the wiki page.

He meant, you need to just make sure `solr_details` field is defined in the `schema.xml`.

Comment: yes my question is: Do i have to include these fields or they are supposed to be there already? and also do i have to modify id,name and desc according to my table fields? or they stay same all the time.

Comment: also there are so many schema.xml files, which one should i be looking at?

Comment: I don't think these fields will be there already. The wiki is just an example, please take the concept and apply it to your own data model.

Comment: Yes, id,name and desc should match the columns you select in the query. You can also use aliasing with AS keyword.

Comment: Not sure where you are looking, if you are looking into example which comes with solr distribution, you will see only one schema.xml under collection1/conf

Comment: thnx i found the schema, can u please explain "id,name, and desc should match the columns you select in the query. You can also use aliasing with AS keyword"?

Comment: if i have to add these fields in schema where will i do that and how:

Comment: I think you need to go through some tutorials on schema and etc. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371247/are-there-any-good-tutorials-for-solr-for-a-noob

Comment: you need to configure a query in your data-config.xml. In the query you will have some select columns (select id, name ....). I was referring to these columns.

Comment: hey, once i index my data into solr. how can i connect solr to my website? and also how can i search through that data?

Comment: I want it to do the following: if i put any word that is included in any file i have uploaded, it should return those documents or file or data back to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define solr schema before using Data Import Handler. 
Follow the [link] (http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html) or https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields